# Tips on using preprocessor #ifndef

Tags: c

I'm learning C and hope someone can explain what's the logic of using `#ifndef`?

I also find many C programs I looked, people seems following a convention using the filename following the `#ifndef`, `#define` and `#endif`. Is there any rule or tip on how to choose this name?

```
#ifndef BITSTREAM_H
#define BITSTREAM_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/*Some functions*/

#endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [best-practice on C header files with #ifndef #define #endif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939368/best-practice-on-c-header-files-with-ifndef-define-endif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for what you're looking for is Preprocessor Directives.

`#ifndef` doesn't need to be followed by a filename, for example it's common to see `#ifdef WINDOWS` or `#ifndef WINDOWS`, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks, David Heffernan, for adding the escapes for me.

Answer (score 5):

Header files will often use logic like this to avoid being included
more than once. The first time a source file includes them, the name
isn't defined, so it gets defined and other things are done.
Subsequent times, the name is defined, so all that is skipped.

Comment: skipped but still parsed lexically.

Comment: Naturally, how else could it find the `#endif`?

Comment: it could be different if there was an `#endinput`directive (like in TeX). Then you could write `#ifdef BITSTREAM_H #endinput #endif`(one directive per line of course).

Answer (score 2):

The one you posted, in particular, is called an [Include Guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 0):

`#ifndef` means "if not defined". It is commonly used to avoid multiple `include`'s of a file.

Answer (score -1):

Tom Zych: "Header files will often use logic like this to avoid being included more than once."

This is true but it really is only necessary for "public" headers, like headers for library functions, where you don't have any control over how the headers are included.

This trick is unnecessary for headers used in projects where you have control over how things are included. (If there's a use for them outside of public headers, it's not a common one).

If you avoid using them in "private" headers, you'll more likely include headers in a less haphazard way.