# Why won't clang compile this source code that works in VS2012?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't for the life of me get clang to compile existing code that compiles fine in `VS2012`.

Includes like `strsafe.h` and `xstring` cause weird compilation errors, the strangest of which is a "missing close bracket" in the middle of a standard include file. Needless to say, there is no missing bracket. Further, `move.h` causes clang to throw up with

> fatal error: expected function body after function declarator.

Guard clauses like

```
#ifndef _FUNCTIONAL_
#error Must include <functional>
#endif
```

throw errors even though functional has been included.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Headers included with one compiler are typically tailored to that compiler implementation and will not necessarily work correctly with a different compiler.

So generally speaking you won't be able use the headers that come with Visual Studio with another compiler.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Code::Blocks to know why it doesn't get configured to use clang correctly. Maybe the problem is that clang isn't installed properly?  Personally, I'd start with making sure you can compile and run a "hello world" program from the command line using clang to make sure it's installed correctly.  That's generally the first thing I do when I install new tools; that's what "hello world" programs are for.

Comment: SO wanted me to move this to chat. Ah well. It seems you're right about the macro name - it's different this time. But it wasn't yesterday (presumably because it was pulling in the VS headers). So...say you're right, and I ought to be including from includes. How do I avoid the aforementioned problems?

Comment: Further, I want to write platform-independent code, that will compile with any fully-functional compiler. What I have is a bunch of VS2012 code.

Comment: @SodAlmighty: instead of your guard clause that you used in your question, just use: `#include <functional>`.  The `functional` header itself will make sure it's not included more than once, so there's generally no harm in including it if your header needs it.

Comment: But that doesn't work when it's my own headers, rather than <functional>, that are being included. And #pragma once or guard clauses don't cut it.

Comment: What doesn't work?  It's perfectly fine to `#include <functional>` in one of your own headers.

Comment: @SodAlmighty: I agree that I probably don't understand. At this point is sounds like your own headers need their own include guards. The names used for those include guards should *not* have anything to do with the names of other headers (your own or system headers). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939368/best-practice-on-c-header-files-with-ifndef-define-endif for some guidance on include guard naming conventions typically used. All header files should have include guards, except for some very rare instances.

Answer (score 7):

Re

> “Includes like strsafe.h and xstring cause weird compilation errors,”

those are Visual C++ headers.

clang probably doesn't have anything like them.

A main problem is that you're using low level C string functions, which Microsoft (rightly!) regards as problematic and (wrongly) convince you are deprecated.

Use `std::string` instead.